# Did Hopkins and Demme purposefully include allusions to Mantegna's paintings of St. Sebastian in "Silence of the Lambs"?

Tags: analysis, the-silence-of-the-lambs

Did Hopkins and Demme purposefully include allusions to Mantegna's paintings of St. Sebastian in *Silence of the Lambs*? It seems so obvious to me but I can find no reference to it online. I would like to know the reasons why. There is a clear reference in the *Hannibal* TV series and of course many references to Hannibal's affinity for art.

Comment: Some examples here would be ideal but the art of William Blake was pretty heavily referenced in *Red Dragon/Manhunter* the prequel.

Comment: At first I thought OP meant the guard that Lecter strung up on the cage, but that didn't really seem like a St. Sebastian pose... But I think OP actually might mean [this moment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3nIw30hn4U#t=1m22s) when Lecter's cuffed against the bars with his hands behind his back and tilts his head dramatically. That's quite astute and a connection I haven't made before.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what moments you are referencing in *Silence of the Lambs*, but in the book *Red Dragon* the victim who leads Will Graham to realize Hannibal is a murderer was found “laced to a pegboard where the [woodworking] tools hung, and he was really torn up, cut and stabbed, and he had arrows in him.” This display of the body vaguely reminded Will of something-- that something has been interpreted by the TV show *Hannibal* to be "The Wound Man", but the mentions of arrows in the book is more similar to St. Sebastian.

Thus, any allusions to St. Sebastian in the film *Silence of the Lambs* are probably references to the way in which Hannibal was apprehended in the books.

The Wound Man:

> [image: Wound man, pierced by several blades]

St. Sebastian:

> [image: St Sebastian pierced by arrows, with his hands tied]